# Create a data.frame with on the fly variable name and value

Tags: r, dataframe

So I'm trying to create a weather dataset in a data.frame that would look like this

```
dayPlus1MinTemp | dayPlus1MaxTemp | dayPlus1Conditions | dayPlus2MinTemp | dayPlus2MaxTemp | dayPlus2Conditions | dayPlus3MinTemp | dayPlus3MaxTemp | dayPlus3Conditions  
7 | 16 | Clear | 8 | 17 | Cloudy | 19 | 36 | Sunny
```

I'm tryin to make a for loop to do that and don't manage to.

```
dataFrameForecast <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:10) {
            buffer1 <- paste0("dayPlus",i,"MinTemp")
            buffer2 <- paste0("dayPlus",i,"MaxTemp")
            buffer3 <- paste0("dayPlus",i,"Conditions")
            assign(buffer1, resForecastTest2inList$forecast$simpleforecast$forecastday[[i]]$low$celsius)
            assign(buffer2, resForecastTest2inList$forecast$simpleforecast$forecastday[[i]]$high$celsius)
            assign(buffer3, resForecastTest2inList$forecast$simpleforecast$forecastday[[i]]$conditions)
            dataFrameForecast <- data.frame(
                    buffer1 = get(buffer1),
                    buffer2 = get(buffer2),
                    buffer3 = get(buffer3)
            )
            dataFrameForecast <- cbind(dataFrameForecast, dataFrameForecast)
    }
```

I have tried this and many other variant but I don't manage to get what I want in the column names at the same time as I get the value assigned to my on the fly created variable.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What is `resForecastTest2inList`? Please, provide a reproducible example and explain what you are trying to achieve. Are you extracting data from a big list? Which is the structure of such list? Which data you want to extract? What do you mean by "on the fly"?

Comment: Well, I don't think it's anyhow useful. But as you ask :  
resForecastTest2inList$forecast$simpleforecast$forecastday[[i]]$low$celsius would be a number like "7"
resForecastTest2inList$forecast$simpleforecast$forecastday[[i]]$high$celsius) would be another nulber like "16"
resForecastTest2inList$forecast$simpleforecast$forecastday[[i]]$conditions
would be a conditions like "Clear"

Comment: It would be more useful to explain what type of object `resForecastTest2inList` is. Also, a reproducible example with shortly named variables containing real numbers would help, so that we can easily answer on the basis of your simplified code and you'd adapt it to your original situation.

Comment: My point is simply that if you provide in your question a variable (with a short name) with a clear structure and real values for `resForecastTest2inList`, it becomes easy for someone here to understand what you want and propose a nice solution for you. BTW, from what I understand, it seems you want to finish with a 1-line `data.frame` with a very high number of columns... wouldn't it be more comfortable to finish with a 3-columns (`Min`, `Max` and `Conditions`) with one row for each forecast day?

Comment: Well I just copy/paste one part of my code and I shouldn't have...  

But the first three set of answers of resForecastTest2inList are in the data.frame result example I gave in the beginning of my question.  

And thanks for the propositions but there are many reasons why I need it to be a one line many columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood:

```
 #it seems that you are using just this part of the list
 sublist<-resForecastTest2inList$forecast$simpleforecast$forecastday[1:10]
 #get all the lows, highs and conditions
 lows<-lapply(sublist,function(x) x$low$celsius)
 highs<-lapply(sublist,function(x) x$high$celsius)
 cond<-lapply(sublist,function(x) x$conditions)
 #set the names
 names(lows)<-paste0("dayPlus",1:10,"MinTemp")
 names(highs)<-paste0("dayPlus",1:10,"MaxTemp")
 names(cond)<-paste0("dayPlus",1:10,"Conditions")
 #get the result
 res<-do.call(data.frame,c(lows,highs,cond))
 #shuffle the result so to have the desired column order
 res[t(matrix(seq_along(res),ncol=3))]
```

Very likely that the above won't work, since you didn't bother to provide a reproducible example. However, it might be useful to see how to get a list with `lapply` and how to set names to it. If that shouldn't work, at least you could provide what objects `lows`, `highs` and `cond` are to see if we can move from there.

Comment: That's nearly what I wanted and it will do it. Is there a better way than to make a for loop to have the result in this order : dayPlus1MinTemp, dayPlus1MaxTemp, dayPlus1Conditions, dayPlus2MinTemp, dayPlus2MaxTemp, etc.

Comment: And I nearly forgot : Thanks ! (It's much cleaner than what I had written so far)

Comment: Use the `[` operator to change the order of the result. I made an edit to show how you can do it.